# NSLog redirecting to a file will also write to /var/log/system.log

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nslog, freopen

I have application where i have to maintain a log file for that app . I am logging by using NSLog . But this will also write to the system log .How to get rid of this .

Approach :

```
NSString *appending_filename=[log_dir_path stringByAppendingString:@"/MyApp.log"];

const char *log_p = [appending_filename cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

newStderr= freopen(log_p, "a", stderr);

NSLog(@" This should only goes to MyApp.log");
```

Comment: Then why to use NSLog, use some user-defined method for that.

Comment: Because by using NSLog you will get the logs with PID,time,Application name automatically . And you don have to open/close the file descriptor again and again .

Answer (score 0):

NSLog will always log to system log, see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLogv).

You might want to look at this post for some other logging libraries that can do what you want:

[is there a popular open source NSLog replacement that handles enabling only in DEBUG and different log levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320283/is-there-a-popular-open-source-nslog-replacement-that-handles-enabling-only-in-d)

Answer (score 0):

Search in `SO` for `Quietlog` and do the same with google. Copy `Quietlog()` into your program, modify it if needed and then

```
#define NSLog() Quietlog()
```

in your program. So you can redirect (and format) your output to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get any solution for this even after trying different things for a day .So going ahead with the user defined function itself.